# Create cases from incoming emails and social media(twitter,facebook) posts

Tags: lightning, community

can anyone suggest me the best "App Exchange app"  or reference to achieve the below scenario [this is related winter20 release notes]

Scenario:- Create case from email and social media if any one posted their account.

Thanks
Ragav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For "create case from email": See email-to-case: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=setting_up_email-to-case.htm&language=en

For "social media": Assuming you have service cloud licenses, set up social customer service: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=social_customer_service_setup_enable.htm&type=5